# Including Plugin's Java Script File

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am creating a simple Cordova/PhoneGap project.

I have added the Device plugin to the project and it works fine without any issues.

I see that there is a file called device.js file in the plugin's www folder.

Some examples online asks to include the plugin js file in the HTML code and some examples does not talk about it. My example works fine without using it.

When I add other plugisn like contacts also, I see the contacts.js file. This make me think twice.

I am confused whether I should use those JS file in my project.

Comment: It depends on what version of cordova the plugin is built for. In older versions you would have to include in the JS in your html file. In newer versions `cordova_plugins.js` includes these files for you. I would start by installing the plugin and then if it doesn't work, try adding the JS include. If it still doesn't work, the plugin may not be compatible with your version of cordova

Comment: I am using the plugins for latest cordava version. So you mean, I don't need to include them in my HTML code?

Comment: Also where can I find the cordova_plugins.js file? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Correct, if you are using the latest version of Cordova and the core plugins, you don't need to include the JS files in your html. The plugins file is added to the platforms, so once you build you will find `/platforms/android/assets/www` and `/platforms/ios/www` not sure about other platforms but similar

Comment: Great.. I found that. So I assume that cordova_plugins.js file will be included in the html files during run time automatically.. Can you add your response as an answer, so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what version of cordova the plugin is built for. In older versions you would have to include in the JS in your html file. In newer versions cordova_plugins.js includes these files for you. I would start by installing the plugin and then if it doesn't work, try adding the JS include. If it still doesn't work, the plugin may not be compatible with your version of cordova

You can check to see if a plugin has been added by looking through `cordova_plugins.js`. This file is placed within each platform, here is iOS and Android:

Android: `/platforms/android/assets/www`

iOS: `/platforms/ios/www`

`cordova.js` (the one file you do need to include in your html) looks for `cordova_plugins.js` and includes it for you which then includes all the plugins listed within it.